# warning NETSDK1080: A PackageReference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is not necessary when targeting .NET Core 3.0 or higher

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, warnings

How do I fix the nasty warning I'm getting when running .NET Core tests from a command line via `dotnet test`?

The `dotnet --version` returns back `3.1.101`.

> ```sh
> $ dotnet test
> watch : Started
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(151,5):
>     warning NETSDK1080: A PackageReference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is not necessary when targeting
>     .NET Core 3.0 or higher. If Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web is used, the shared framework will be referenced automatically.
>     Otherwise, the PackageReference should be replaced with a FrameworkReference.
>     [C:\github\demo\Demo\SmartHome.API\SmartHome.API.csproj]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(151,5):
>     warning NETSDK1080: A PackageReference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is not necessary when targeting
>     .NET Core 3.0 or higher. If Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web is used, the shared framework will be referenced automatically.
>     Otherwise, the PackageReference should be replaced with a FrameworkReference.
>     [C:\github\demo\Demo\SmartHome.API\SmartHome.API.csproj]
> Test run for C:\github\demo\Demo\SmartHome.API.Test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SmartHome.API.Test.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)
> Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.3.0
> Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Starting test execution, please wait...
>
> A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
> ```

Here's what my `SmartHome.API.Test.csproj` looks like.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="5.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.10.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SmartHome.API\SmartHome.API.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SmartHome.Models\SmartHome.API.Models.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And this is the `SmartHome.API.csproj` which seems to be the source of the issue.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="8.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.2.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.10.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SmartHome.Models\SmartHome.API.Models.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Changing a package dependency from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` (2.2.8) into a `FrameworkReference` in the `SmartHome.API.csproj` solved the problem for me at the cost of introducing a new one.

## Initial fix

```
+  <ItemGroup>                                                                                                                         
+    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />                                                                         
+  </ItemGroup>                                                                                                                        
+                                                                                                                                      
   <ItemGroup>                                                                                                                         
     <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="8.6.1" />                                                                   
-    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.2.8" />                                                           
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.1" />                                      
     <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.10.1" />                                                                    
   </ItemGroup>
```

## New warning

I started seeing a new warning:

> ```
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\
>   Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(39,5):
> warning NETSDK1086: A FrameworkReference for 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App' was 
>   included in the project. This is implicitly referenced by the .NET SDK and you
>   do not typically need to reference it from your project. For more information,
>   see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicitrefs
> ```

## Final fix

...so I ended up removing the `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"` reference altogether. Now the build is warning-free!

i.e. the file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="8.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.10.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SmartHome.Models\SmartHome.API.Models.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```